# How do I stop previously trained dog from peeing in house

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

Reese is 8 years old. She has no medical issues. She pees in house, sometimes poops when I'm not home. This started about a year ago. I tried to lock her in my bathroom when I left, but after a month, she was still barking and getting frantic in there - chewing up her bedding, scratching the door, etc. She is on Xanax now and that is not helping. I don't make a big deal when I leave or come back. I have put my dining room chairs along the path where she usually pees and that is a deterrent, but my house looks crazy. I'm guessing that something outside gets her excited and she runs over to pee and then the chairs distract her and she doesn't. I was thinking about getting a surveillance camera so that I could watch her and talk to her when I see her going to pre, but obviously can't keep doing that. Any ideas?

Comment: (If you do) How often do you take her out for a walk?

Answer (score 2):

You do what she should do as a puppy, if she gives a sign that she needs to go or when she just finishes going take her quickly outside and keep her out for a good minute or after you clean up, then she should understand it is not acceptable, or if you like you can get large dog litter trays or pads and train her to go on those, she sounds as if she is an oldie and maybe forgetting where she needs to go or she can't get there on time.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a camera, at least for a while, will let you see what he's doing when he misbehaves. Maybe something *is* setting him off; maybe there is more complex behavior that would be a clue.

This doesn't have to be monitored surveillance;  just a recording to review later. A GoPro or webcam woukd do nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can't stop them I have a 2 year old bitch and she does it. It is anxiety of you not being there which is why they do it. I just put tarpooling down for my dog when I lock her away and go out.